# Blogger's Flipcard Effect using jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Is there any plugin in jQuery that can give result like Flipcard effect in Blogger's Dynamic View ?

For example of this effect please visit http://gmailblog.blogspot.com and click on Flipcard menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go...

http://jonraasch.com/blog/quickflip-2-jquery-plugin

Good Luck!