# How to get this web effect for screen thumbnails?

Tags: jquery, css

When hovering over each icon in http://www.ariasblog.ca/ there is a "rotating effect" before the relevant text is displayed.
I assume it's a jquery script that is called from hovering on a link. Is there a specific script on opensource, or does it have to be written specifically for a site?

Comment: There are hundreds of plugins for this effect. Google it (jQuery flip).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Blogger's Flipcard Effect using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191046/bloggers-flipcard-effect-using-jquery)

Comment: thanks for the mention of Bloggers Flipcard Effect. Obviously I didn't know of that particular site implementation, but always good to add to the knowledge bank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any of these jQuery plugins

- [Flip!](http://lab.smashup.it/flip/)
- [QuickFlip 2](http://jonraasch.com/blog/quickflip-2-jquery-plugin)

Comment: Great quick answer - many thanks. Will accept this when site allows..

Comment: Strange though that something "that cannot be reasonably answered in its current form" was so quickly answered?

Comment: @DBMarcos99 i voted to close as a duplicate ....

Comment: thanks for that, fair comment - it makes a lot more sense.